# Is there any type of food capable enough to change the contents of causal body?

Tags: scripture, food, jiva, ayurveda

According to Sanatana Dharma, a Jeeva or human contains three bodies: Physical body, subtle body, and causal body.

It is well known that food can directly impact the physical body. We can also notice that some kinds of foods can also show their impacts on the subtle body.

I want to know whether there is any effect of food on the causal body.

Are there any verses in scriptures saying that some kinds of food show an impact on the causal body?

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, causal body cant be influenced, only Linga shareera and Sthoola can be influenced with food which is Sattvik. Causal body can't be influenced, int can only be either left to exist, as it has existed from eternity or dismantled. It can't be changed, it can be dismantled or dissolved. This ks known as Moksha.